# How to render a jinja html list with two lists using Python and Flask?

Tags: python, html, for-loop, flask

I'm working on a dynamic table with some entries extracted from a database with a simple Python conection. I'm working with Flask and Jinja for the rendering of the HTML.

For achieving this, I use a cur.fetchall():

```py
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM conceptos WHERE conceptos.conceptoTipo = 1')
data = cur.fetchall()
```

But, I'm interested on modifying an specific value from each entry, in this case the value on the 9th position.And, for that, I create a list and use a *for* to go through the entries in the *data*, like this:

```py
x = []
for i in data:
    x.append(i[9]+1) #Just adding 1 to the numeric value for testing the change.
```

And lastly, I return both variables with the render_template:

```py
return render_template('descuentosBeneficiarios.html', conceptos = data, operas = x)
```

Inside the HTML, I use Jinja2 to expose the variables dynamically inside a simple table:

```html
{% for concepto in conceptos %}

<tr>
  <!-- Recorrer Campos de Tabla-->
  <td>{{concepto.0}}</td>
  <td>{{operas}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.2}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.3}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.4}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.5}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.6}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.7}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.8}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.9}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.10}}</td>
  <td>{{concepto.11}}</td>
  <td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

As a result, for each row I'm getting all the values inside the *operas* list on the second column, and I only need the first for the first row, the second for the second, and so on, but I don't know how to do that.

Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Well here are a lot of assumptions on my side, but if the length of the `operas` is equal to the length of elements in `conceptos` you could use the `loop.index` to access the needed element.

```html
{% for concepto in conceptos %}
<tr>
  <td>{{concepto.0}}</td>
  <td>{{operas[loop.index]}}</td>
  <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

But if you just need to modify one value from `data` why use a second list? Will tis not fix the problem:

```py
for i in data:
    i[9] += 1
```

Or if you need the 9th elements original value:

```py
for i in data:
    i.append(i[9] + 1)
```

So this way you will have it as 12th element.

As I said there are a lot of assumptions.